# packing a php self contained executable with my application

Tags: php, macos, cocoa, command-line-interface, xojo

I am building a mac application using Xojo framework,

the app i am building have to run php as a command line, i could use the php that ships with mac osx
however i need a php with mcrypt extension, and the one built into the osx does not have the mcrypt and i don't want to force my customers to update their php,

so the optimal solution that i could think of, is to pack a php self contained executable with my application

is this possible? and how to go for it?

Comment: if your application needs to be an executable, php is one of the worse languages to write it in.

Comment: i need to run some php scripts from inside my application

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sounds possible.

In the Xojo IDE you could insert a Copy Files build step after the OS X build that copies your php executable into the resources folder of your built app.

Then in your App.Open you could copy that executable to wherever you want to from that SpecialFolder, or just reference it as is in your command lines depending on whether there are any restrictions imposed on how your are distributing the app (i.e. App Store).

Check out http://docs.xojo.com/index.php/SpecialFolder for some guidance on where to copy any files you need to bundle or how to reference them.